# Using data pulled from an API

Tags: javascript, api

It's been half a day now of trying to figure this out, and while some progress has been made, and a ton of useful research, I'm still a newbie so I need help.

What I need is to use the data that I'm pulling from an API to use as a JS variable. My [API](https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=usd&include_market_cap=false&include_24hr_vol=false&include_24hr_change=true) is giving me the following output:

```
{"bitcoin":{"usd":9695.66,"usd_24h_change":2.0385849528977977}}
```

I want to use the `usd` and `usd_24_change` values from that string, maybe as some JS variable for further calculations.

So far what I've managed to do was to  push the string directly in HTML, so I can have a visual representation of it, however I need to pull the values from it in the backend (hope that makes sense?)

My code so far:

```js
fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => {
    $('#apiPlaceholder').html(data);
  });
```

I've honestly ran out of ideas. My only alternative would be trying to pull the values directly from the HTML string but I feel like that would be a really clunky way of doing it. I'm sure there's ways to interpret the data in the backend.

Any ideas would definitely be appreciated! :)

Comment: use `response.json()` - that will give you a deserialized form of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you would go about doing that:

```
fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data["bitcoin"]["usd"]);
    console.log(data["bitcoin"]["usd_24h_change"]);
  });
```

Comment: Man, this actually helped me figure it out! Thank you so very much. I wasn't actually looking to just display it in the console but the syntax of pulling the data helped me out! Thanks a million - basically answered my question!

Answer (score 0):

you need to parse the response and then just save it.

```
 fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => {
    const parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
    const usd = parsedData.bitcoin.usd;
    const usd_24h_change = parsedData.bitcoin.usd_24h_change;
  });
```

or display it instead;

Comment: Thanks Vlad! Think I tried something along these lines, but not having done it before I probably missed something or made some syntax error. Either way, the response above you actually solved it for me but nonetheless I genuinely appreciate your reply. Maybe I'll use this as well in the future :)

Comment: basically its the same thing, but the previous answer uses a build in parser, which is nicer and more elegant. i'm not using fetch API everyday, so i forgot about this option.